# Inserting a Lipschitz function between two continuous functions

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity, lipschitz-functions

I am reading a proof that uses the following fact which I cannot show:

> Let $b_1, b_2 : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions such that $b_1 (x) < b_2 (x),$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Then, for each integer $m \geq 3$, there exists a Lipschitz-continuous function $b_m: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that
>   $$ b_1 (x) \leq b_m (x) \leq b_2 (x), \text{ for } |x| \leq m.$$

Any ideas on how to show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For given $m$, on the bounded and closed interval $[-m,m]$ the difference of the functions is bounded from below by a constant $\eta>0$. In other words, there is a 'tube' of width $\eta $ between the graphs of these functions.

Moreover, on that interval, they are both uniformly continuous. So you may assume that there is $\delta>0$ such that for both functions $b_i$, the implication $|x-y|\le \delta \Rightarrow |b_i(x)-b_i(y) |\le \frac{1}{2}\eta$, say, is true.

Now with this information you can create a piecewise linear function by looking at a partition of width $\delta$ of the interval $[-m,m]$ by adding linear pieces from left to right which remain in the tube between the graphs of the $b_i$. (This is a bit of a nasty task which I will not carry out in detail, but it's not too difficult). That piecewise linear function will be Lipshitz, the Lipshitz constant given by the subinterval of lenght $\delta$ with the steepest slope of that piecewise linear function.

**Alternatively** you may use the fact (if you know it) that the polynomials (or the smooth functions) are dense in the space of continuous functions. With $\eta$ as above, choose a polynomial which is $\frac{\eta}{4}$ close to the upper function $b_2$ and move it down by $\frac{\eta}{2}$